# Moved from Jquery 1.2.6 to 1.4.1 > Script errors :(

Tags: jquery

Ive been playing with some jQuery script that was originally written using 1.2.6.
I want to use his try this script along side some other jquery stuff whilst moving upto the latest 1.4.1, however i get an error.

The code is:

```
    GlobalHeader={
    globalNav:function(){
        var recipeLbl="recipes-and-cooking";
        var navTimer=null;
        var bodyId=document.body.id;
        bodyId=(bodyId=='shows'||bodyId=='chefs')?bodyId:recipeLbl;
        var initializeMenu="#sub-nav-"+bodyId+" li";
        hideAll();

        initMenu(initializeMenu);

        function initMenu(initializeMenu){
            var menu=initializeMenu;
            $(menu).find('h3:first span').click(function(){hideAll();});
            $(menu+"[@class ^= 'nav-']").each(function(i){$(this).hover(
                function(e){
                    hideAll();
                    var $this=$(this);
                    var offsetVal="auto";
                    var divs=$(this).nextAll();
                    var width=0;

                    jQuery.each(divs,function(){width=width+parseInt($(this).width());});
                    if($this.hasClass("nav-e")){
                        offsetVal=(($(this).parents().filter('ul').width()-$(this).find('div.drop').width())-width);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if((jQuery.browser.msie)&&(jQuery.browser.version==6)){
                            offsetVal=($(this).parents().filter('ul').width()-width)-parseInt($(this).width())-7;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            offsetVal="auto";
                        }
                    }
                    $('body').bind("click",function(e){bodyClick(e);});
                    navTimer=setTimeout(function(){
                        $this.find('div.drop').css({
                            left:offsetVal,top:"28px",background:"none",display:"block"
                        });
                    navTimer=null;},375);
                },
        function(e){
        clearTimeout(navTimer);
        navTimer=null;
        var closeDiv=$(this);
        if(jQuery.browser.msie){$(this).find('div.drop').css({background:"b2b2b2"});}
        navTimer=setTimeout(function(){
            closeDiv.find('div.drop').css({top:"28px",display:"none",display:"none"});
            navTimer=null;}
        ,100);}
    );}
    )
;}
function bodyClick(e){var $clicked=$(e.target);if($clicked.parents().is('.drop')){return false;}else{hideAll();$('body').unbind();}}
function hideAll(){clearTimeout(navTimer);navTimer=null;$("#sub-nav li[@class ^= 'nav-'] div.drop").each(function(){$(this).css({display:"none"});});}
}};
```

However, it errors at this line $(menu+"[@class ^= 'nav-']").each(function(i){$(this).hover(
saying undefined is null.  jQuery 1.4.1 also errors complaining of a "thrown but not caught" error.

Can anyone spot the fix?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@` was [removed from attribute selectors in jQuery 1.3+](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.3#Upgrading), it should now just be:

```
$(menu+"[class^='nav-']")
```

You can view a full list of the current attribute selectors for jQuery 1.4+ (or whatever the current version is...this answer will grow old :) here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Your `hideAll()` function at the bottom will need the same treatment:

```
$("#sub-nav li[class^='nav-'] div.drop")
```

One last note, the latest as of this answer is jQuery 1.4.**2**, might as well get all the latest [bug fixes and methods it includes](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.4.2/), you can always find the latest version here: http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Download_jQuery

Comment: Wow! That was quick!! Thanks Nick ... that solved my problems :)
I cant believe I missed it grrr.... also, my mistake - I already have 1.4.2 :)

Thanks again

Comment: @jtanner - Welcome, and welcome to SO :) Be sure to accept answers, enjoy the music and have a nice day!